# TypeORM CLI: No changes in database schema were found

Tags: migration, nestjs, typeorm

I'm am developing an application using NestJS and TypeORM. Whenever I try to generate migrations from my entities (by running `typeorm migration:generate`) I get the following message:

```
No changes in database schema were found - cannot generate a migration. To create a new empty migration use "typeorm migration:create" command
```

I even deleted all the existing migration files (from migrations folder) to exclude any possibility of conflict.

The problem begun after I changed my application's modules folders structure to:

```
src
 |- config
 |   |- database
 |       |- mysql
 |           |- cli-configuration.ts
 |- migrations
 |- module1
     |- controller
     |- entity
     |- service
```

As can be seen, the `migrations` folder is right under `src` and each module has an `entity` folder, where the entities for that module are placed. All the ormconfig settings come from `cli-configuration.ts` file.

In `package.json` file I added the following to `scripts`:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js --config src/config/database/mysql/cli-configuration.ts",
    "typeorm:migrate": "npm run typeorm migration:generate -- -n",
    "typeorm:run": "npm run typeorm migration:run"
  }
}
```

The content of `src/config/database/mysql/cli-configuration.ts` file is:

```js
import * as path from 'path';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config({
  // Path relative to project root folder (because cli command is invoked from there)
  path: path.resolve('environment', (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") ? ".env.production" : ".env")
});

const config = {
  type: "mysql",
  host: process.env.TYPEORM_HOST,
  port: Number(process.env.TYPEORM_PORT),
  username: process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE,
  entities: [path.resolve('src', process.env.TYPEORM_ENTITIES)],

  // We are using migrations, synchronize should be set to false.
  synchronize: false,

  // Run migrations automatically,
  // you can disable this if you prefer running migration manually.
  migrationsRun: true,
  logging: process.env.TYPEORM_LOGGING,

  // Allow both start:prod and start:dev to use migrations
  // __dirname is either dist or src folder, meaning either
  // the compiled js in prod or the ts in dev.
  migrations: [path.resolve('src', process.env.TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS)],
  cli: {
    // Location of migration should be inside src folder
    // to be compiled into dist/ folder.
    // entitiesDir: process.env.TYPEORM_ENTITIES_DIR,
    migrationsDir: path.resolve('src', process.env.TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_DIR),
    // subscribersDir: process.env.TYPEORM_SUBSCRIBERS_DIR,
  },
  dropSchema: false
};

export = config;
```

Running `console.log(config)` I get:

```
{
  type: 'mysql',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3306,
  username: 'root',
  password: 'root',
  database: 'myapp',
  entities: [ '/var/www/html/myapp/src/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}' ],
  synchronize: false,
  migrationsRun: true,
  logging: 'all',
  migrations: [ '/var/www/html/myapp/src/migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}' ],
  cli: { migrationsDir: '/var/www/html/myapp/src/migrations' },
  dropSchema: false
}
```

**Last but not least....** After spending hours on this issue (making changes to migrations and entities paths, hard-coding values besides getting them from process.env, etc), I tried to execute `yarn run typeorm schema:log` (`npm run` works as well). I got surprised when I saw that all the content that I expected to be in the migration file I am trying to generate was output to console.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `permission_permission` (`id` varchar(36) NOT NULL, `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL, `code` text NOT NULL, `create_date` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6), `update_date` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6), `delete_date` datetime(6) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE `permission_role` (`id` varchar(36) NOT NULL, `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL, `code` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `create_date` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6), `update_date` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6), `delete_date` datetime(6) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE `user_user` (`id` varchar(36) NOT NULL, `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `is_active` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `create_date` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6), `update_date` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6), `delete_date` datetime(6) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE `permission_role_permission` (`permission_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL, `role_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL, INDEX `IDX_3247040996395a5faea3c9b3a5` (`permission_id`), INDEX `IDX_7d9cfbfd027256ab08658bcf6e` (`role_id`), PRIMARY KEY (`permission_id`, `role_id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE `user_user_role` (`role_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL, `user_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL, INDEX `IDX_c0c2bbb31e8e8708efc6dd5a64` (`role_id`), INDEX `IDX_beb8c39c852f4d132ba44b483c` (`user_id`), PRIMARY KEY (`role_id`, `user_id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE `permission_role_permission` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_3247040996395a5faea3c9b3a54` FOREIGN KEY (`permission_id`) REFERENCES `permission_role`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
ALTER TABLE `permission_role_permission` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_7d9cfbfd027256ab08658bcf6e1` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `permission_permission`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
ALTER TABLE `user_user_role` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_c0c2bbb31e8e8708efc6dd5a64b` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `user_user`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
ALTER TABLE `user_user_role` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_beb8c39c852f4d132ba44b483c0` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `permission_role`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Can anyone tell me why is `schema:log` detecting the changes in my entities, but `migration:generate` is not working?

Comment: I have the same problem. However schema:log says "Your schema is up to date..."

Comment: I am having the exactly same issue.

Comment: Did you get solution for this? I am also facing same problem without much luck.

Answer (score 3):

For me [this hint](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/5965#issuecomment-680839366) helped. Just run `npm run build` before generating with `npm run typeorm -- migration:generate -n migration_name` the new migration. Somehow an up to date `dist` folder needs to be present.

Comment: Ive been trying to figure this out for about 8 hours. This was the answer

Answer (score 2):

I was getting exactly the same thing and it seems that an older `0.2.x` version is off. I've been using `0.2.34` and I was getting the issue there.

Moving to `0.2.45` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps that i took to make it work:

1. Add an empty migration and on the `up` method add a query to drop all your tables.

Example:

> await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE "table_name"`);

2. Remove this migration
3. Remove your `dist` folder
4. Remove your `.idea` folder
5. Start your service - i used `nest start` (this should add a new and clean `dist` folder)
6. Check your `ormconfig.json` file for your "migrations" location.

Mine was:

> "migrations": [
> "dist/database/migration/*.js"   ]

6. Check this path in the `dist` folder - i had no folder there with the name "migration".
7. Add the folder `migration` (or use the name you have in the `ormconfig.json`)
8. Run your migration:generate like before and it should work

(`npm run typeorm -- migration:generate -n migration_name`)

Hope it helped!

Comment: How can help step 1? when migration folder is in dist, and if you run yarn build, it removes dist completly and on next run still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This problem appears when something wrong with paths.
I have created a small working project using your configurations and directory style. Here is the link. 
https://github.com/nairi-abgaryan/typeorm-mysql-nestjs

Quick overview.
Updated the `cli-configuration.ts`  file a little bit.
The typeorm lib will use this configuration as you described in package.json.

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import {TypeOrmModuleOptions} from '@nestjs/typeorm/dist/interfaces/typeorm-options.interface';
dotenv.config({
   path: '.env',
});

const config: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  type: 'mysql',
  host: process.env.TYPEORM_HOST,
  port: Number(process.env.TYPEORM_PORT),
  username: process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE,
  autoLoadEntities: true,
  entities: [`${__dirname}/../../../../src/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}`],
  migrations: [`${__dirname}/../../../migrations`],
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: `${__dirname}/../../../migrations`,
  },
  dropSchema: false,
};

export = config;
```

.env

```
TYPEORM_TYPE='mysql'
TYPEORM_HOST=localhost
TYPEORM_PORT=3306
TYPEORM_USERNAME='root'
TYPEORM_PASSWORD='root'
TYPEORM_DATABASE='myapp'
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS='migrations'
```

Also, I created an ormconfig.json file which is for nest js connection to DB. As it says in the documentation when you don't want to config it in the app.module.

> Note that the ormconfig.json file is loaded by the typeorm library.
> Thus, any of the extra properties described above (which are supported
> internally by way of the forRoot() method - for example,
> autoLoadEntities and retryDelay) won't be applied. Luckily, TypeORM
> provides the getConnectionOptions function that reads connection
> options from the ormconfig file or environment variables. With this,
> you can still use the configuration file and set Nest-specific
> options, as follows:

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  useFactory: async () =>
    Object.assign(await getConnectionOptions(), {
      autoLoadEntities: true,
    }),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue on projects with Nestjs + TypeORM + PostgreSQL.

We have found out that TypeORM had a conflict when you have an environment variable with the same value of type.

Check this example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEOuU.jpg

In this case, we have `TYPEORM_TYPE = postgres` and the `type: 'postgres'` for some unknown reason TypeORM cannot resolve and does not find your Database.

So to fix it try to remove it from your .env and try run again!

Hope I could help you or someone ;)

Answer (score -8):

The problem is that `migration:generate` is not being executed for some reason. Try changing your script on `package.json` for
`"migration:create": "npm run typeorm migration:create -n"`